# Generate a Random Int32 for the full range of possible numbers

Tags: c#, random

If I wanted to generate a random number for all possible numbers an Int32 could contain would the following code be a reasonable way of doing so?  Is there any reason why it may not be a good idea? (ie. a uniform distribution at least as good as Random.Next() itself anyway)

```
    public static int NextInt(Random Rnd) //-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
    {
         int AnInt;
         AnInt = Rnd.Next(System.Int32.MinValue, System.Int32.MaxValue);
         AnInt += Rnd.Next(2);
         return AnInt;
    }
```

Comment: Isn't `AnInt += Rnd.Next(2);` the same as `AnInt+=1`?

Comment: You want every number in a range to be output once, randomly?

Comment: It will either add 0 or 1 allowing us to reach the maximum possible value for an Int32.  Random.Next() wont do that for us unfortunately.  It's a bit of a design flaw you might say

Comment: No I don't want every number to be output once.  As far as I'm aware the more evenly distributed numbers are from a random number generator the more random they are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed solution will slightly skew the distribution. The minValue and maxValue will occur less frequently than the interior values. As an example, assume that int has a MinValue of -2 and a MaxValue of 1. Here are the possible initial values, with each followed by the resulting values after the Random(2):

```
-2: -2 -1
-1: -1  0
 0:  0  1
```

half of the negative -2 values will get modified up to -1, and only half of 0 will get modified up to 1. So the values -2 and 1 will occur less frequently than -1 and 0.

Damien's solution is good. Another choice would be:

```
if (Random(2) == 0) {
    return Random(int.MinValue, 0);
} else {
    return 1 + Random(-1, int.MaxValue);
}
```

another solution, similar to Damiens approach, and faster than the previous one would be

```
 int i = r.Next(ushort.MinValue, ushort.MaxValue + 1) << 16;
 i |= r.Next(ushort.MinValue, ushort.MaxValue + 1);
```

Comment: I like what you've done there.  I was also thinking of something along the lines of what you've done in your code sample.  Can you explain why the values get modified? I'm not sure I follow you there

Comment: approximately half the time it picks from the lower half of int's range (-2,147,483,648..-1) and the other half of the time it picks from the upper half of int's range (0..2,147,483,647). Damien's solution will run slightly faster than this though.

Comment: Yes, a quick test on my system reveals that Damien's solution is indeed about 1.6 times as fast as the above code.

Comment: Although you second solution may actually be the fastest just by a whisker

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Random.NextBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextbytes) to obtain 4 bytes, then use [`BitConverter.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32) to convert those to an `int`.

Something like:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[4];
Rnd.NextBytes(buf);
int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(buf,0);
```

Comment: This doesn't specifically answer my question but I like your solution thanks!

Comment: @PaulMatthews - what aspect(s) of your question have I missed out on?

Comment: I specifically asked would my code be a reasonable solution and if not why not.

Comment: @PaulMatthews - I think hatchet's answer addresses some possible skew issues.

Comment: For most cases this solution is ok, however the documentation is not 100% true so it's broken (not Damiens fault). Internally this method calls `Next()%256` for each byte, and since int.MaxValue is missing it means that it will return the value 255 (0xFF) slightly less often than any other value.  The discrepancy is only ~0,000'012% though, but it compounds because an int contains 4 bytes. For example it will make the number -1 (0xFFFFFFFF) the least likely number to occur. So this will "solve" the problem by (unevenly) stealing very small amounts of probability from 8'388'607 other numbers.

Comment: (cont...) For all intents and purposes though this will most likely be unnoticeable so don't worry too much about it. However since generating 4 bytes means calling `Next()` 4 times there are better ways to do this (such as the accepted answer for example - or other much more advanced methods).

Answer (score 0):

A [uniform distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28discrete%29) does not mean you get each number exactly once. For that you need a [permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation)

Now, if you need a random permutation of *all* 4-billion numbers you're a bit stuck. .NET does not allow objects to be larger than 2GBs. You can work around that, but I assume that's not really what you need.

If you less numbers (say, 100, or 5 million, less than a few billions) without repetitions, you should do this:

Maintain a set of integers, starting empty. Choose a random number. If it's already in the set, choose another random number. If it's not in the set, add it and return it.

That way you guarantee each number will be returned only once.

Comment: You can store all 4 billion integers in a bit array. Where each bit represents a number and if the bit is 0 then that number has not been seen and if it is a 1 it has been seen. This brings the memory use down to 512mb.

Comment: Yes, you can. As I said, there are ways around the 2GB limitation, that's one of them. However, I don't think OP wants a permutation of 4 billion numbers, it makes very little sense.

Answer (score 0):

I have a class where I get random bytes into a 8KB buffer and distribute numbers from by converting them from the random bytes. This gives you the full int distribution. The 8KB buffer is used to you do not need to call NextBytes for every new random byte[].

```
    // Get 4 bytes from the random buffer and cast to int (all numbers equally this way 
    public int GetRandomInt()
    {
        CheckBuf(sizeof(int));
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(_buf, _idx);
    }

    // Get bytes for your buffer. Both random class and cryptoAPI support this
    protected override void GetNewBuf(byte[] buf)
    {
        _rnd.NextBytes(buf);
    }

    // cyrptoAPI does better random numbers but is slower
    public StrongRandomNumberGenerator()
    {
        _rnd = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    }
```